# How are the throat slitting scenes created in Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones, behind-the-scenes, special-effects

I am currently watching Game of Thrones S3, where a character’s throat is slit.

In scenes such as this, how is the fake wound and blood spray created? Also, how do actors provide perfect expressions of throat being slit?

(I haven't seen how a person dies when throat is slit in real life or any video of a real person being killed in such a manner, so I also can't judge if these scenes are realistically designed.)

I suppose the whole scene is computer generated.

Comment: @DrRDizzle this question is about "behind the scenes" information for a fantasy work, it's clearly on topic. It might get *better* answers on M&TV but that's the OP's choice. (Or it might already be answered, as I psychically predict to be the case.)

Comment: This question has already been asked on Movies Stack Exchange: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/how-are-head-shots-and-deep-throat-gashes-filmed

Comment: I read the original revision, it asked about Game of Thrones (and also Breaking Bad). That's good enough to be on-topic.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield It used *Game of Thrones* and *Breaking Bad* as examples, but the question was asking about the technique in general, not specific to the episodes in question. If I asked "I saw *Titan A.E* the other day, which is an animated film. How are animated films created?" it wouldn't be on topic, and this question read similar to that. Now it is focused on the particular *Game of Thrones* episode, it is on-topic and I am retracting my close vote.

Comment: I agree with the above commenters that this question is **on-topic**, and am reopening it. Behind-the-scenes questions are allowed according to the [help centre](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), provided they relate to a work of science fiction or fantasy (in this case, Game of Thrones).

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR: To answer your question specifically, the throat-slashing was a mixture of prosthetic wounds and CGI done in post-production.**

** Spoilerish discussion of S03E09 "The Rains of Castamere" **

Special effects artist [**Sangeet Prabhaker**](http://www.studiosangeet.com/) was responsible for sculpting the neck wounds we are (probably) discussing. After the airing of episode S03E09 "[**The Rains of Castamere**](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Rains_of_Castamere_(episode))", Prabhaker posted several BTS photos of his work. The photos included the neck prosthetics used on

> actresses [Michelle Fairley](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Michelle_Fairley) (Caitlyn Stark) and [Kelly Long](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Kelly_Long) (Frey's wife) in the Red Wedding scene.

After they were filmed with and without the prosthetics in place, CGI was used to perform the actual "slashing", transitioning between the before and after shots. Most of the blood in those scenes was CGI as well, although the blood stains on clothing was actual stage blood.

Here are a couple of related links if you'd like to learn more:

- http://io9.com/game-of-thrones-gag-inducing-prosthetics-are-amazing-1588651613
- http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/2013/6/7/saying-goodbye-behind-the-scenes-of-episode-309.html

And also a video discussing how the scene was made:

Comment: Video discusses everything and *shows* nothing, behind the scenes.

Comment: The video is dead.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out following links:

**[wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Horror-Scene-With-a-Slit-Throat)**

Comment: Might want to spoiler tag that video. Ewwwww.

Comment: @Omegacron  :-)  Still "slit throat" is perhaps a hint in itself that the clip won't be nice...

Comment: Um yeah take this preview off please. Gees.

Comment: This is what I came to see.

Comment: Guy was dead anyway, since it appears most of his blood is clotted as it comes out of his throat.

Comment: This looks like a "link-only" answer. What if the video and the wikihow page disappeared?